# IntelliJ Javascript inheritance visualization

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I discovered recently that IntelliJ (and Webstorm, PHPStorm and other JetBrains products) honor somehow semantics in javasctipt files to detect class inheritance. This seems to be working for strings

```
var A = Class.create({});
var B = Class.create(A, {});
```

When I use this syntax, IntelliJ just knows that there is a relationship base->subclass between those two and allows me to use all the navigation features for classes.

This ends when I use some scope for that, like

```
var a = XX.Class.create({});
var b = XX.Class.create(a, {});
```

Is there any possibility to extend this behavior to other patterns? Or am I missing something?